# How to see the elements of a struct

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

I have some results like:

```
    KinDetail = 

        []    [1x12 struct]    [1x72 struct]    [1x432 struct]    [1x2592 struct]

    KinDetail{2}

    ans = 

    1x12 struct array with fields:

        Comp
        DHtab
        jt

KinDetail{2}.DHtab

ans =

         0   -1.5708         0    0.1000
         0         0         0    0.9500
.
.
.
.

ans =

         0   -1.5708         0    0.8500
         0         0         0    0.2000
```

I need all results for each element of the struct. When I write KinDetail{2}.DHtab(1) Iexpect to see:

```
KinDetail{2}.DHtab(1)=

         0   -1.5708         0    0.1000
         0         0         0    0.9500
```

but it gives error and says:

```
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 12 results.
```

How can I get each result individually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've placed the `(1)` in the wrong place. Try

```
KinDetail{2}(1).DHtab
```

instead.

#### Explanation

Calling `KinDetail{2}.DHtab(1)` attempts to get the first value in `kinDetail{2}.DHtab`which is not allowed in heterogeneous data structures.

On the other hand to get the first element of the struct in cell 2 of KinDetail we can call `KinDetail{2}(1)` which then lets us look at the `DHtab` value

```
KinDetail{2}(1).DHtab
```

Furthermore, if you actually wanted to access the first value of each element's `DHtab` you could implement `arrayfun` as such:

```
arrayfun(@(st)st.DHtab(1),KinDetail{2})
```